# Create action - ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, nested-attributes

I'm trying to create clinics associated to the `current user`. But when I hit submit, I get this error.
I'm using devise, rails admin and cancancan. I don't know if any of these could be causing the error, or something else is wrong.

ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in ClinicsController#create
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :clinics, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :clinics, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

end
```

**clinic.rb**

```
class Clinic < ApplicationRecord  

    belongs_to :user   

end
```

**clinics_controller.rb**

```
class ClinicsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_clinic, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @clinic = Clinic.all      
        @user = current_user
     end

     def show
        @clinic = Clinic.find(params[:id])
        @user = current_user
     end

     def edit
        @clinic = Clinic.find(params[:id])
     end


    def new
        @clinic = current_user.clinics.new
    end

    def create
        @clinic = current_user.clinics.new(params[:clinic])

        respond_to do |format|
          if @clinic.save
            format.html { redirect_to @clinic, notice: 'Clinic was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @clinic }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @clinic.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end


      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @clinic.update(params[:clinic])
            format.html { redirect_to @clinic, notice: 'Clinic was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @clinic }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @clinic.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end



  def destroy
    @clinic.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to clinics_url, notice: 'Clinic was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_clinic
      @clinic = Clinic.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user)
      .permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :phone, 
        :practitioner_image,  
        :clinic_logo,
        clinic_images: [],
        profession_ids: [], 
        speciality_ids: [], 
        services_attributes: [:id, :description, :name, :duration, :price, :_destroy], 
        educations_attributes: [:id, :name, :place, :year, :_destroy],
        membership_ids: [],
        awards_attributes: [:id, :name, :year, :_destroy],
        clinics_attributes: [:id, :clinic_name, :clinic_address, :clinic_zip_code, :clinic_municipality, :clinic_about, :clinic_mail, :clinic_phone, :clinic_website, :clinic_city, :_destroy,
        practitioners_attributes: [:id, :public_health_insurance, :practitioner_gender, :practitioner_first_name, :practitioner_last_name, :practitioner_description, :practitioner_mail, :practitioner_phone, :practitioner_website, :_destroy]])

    end
end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<div id="ClinicGenerel" class="TabBlock">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content clinic">
      <h2 class="page-title">Generel information</h2>
      <%= simple_form_for [@clinic] do |f| %>
        <%= render 'clinics_fields', :f => f %>
        <div class="submit-container">
          <%= f.submit "Gem", :class => 'btn blue'  %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Log**

```
Started POST "/clinics" for ::1 at 2020-03-09 20:35:16 +0100
Processing by ClinicsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"lkftNxR96kkoI4+m00fSevQC+dZU9KsqhvWrcWg+7RPNWd593lPj2aWBdM2vfX83k4t2WUb2LODPFJVnFwJkZg==", "clinic"=>{"clinic_name"=>"Testin", "clinic_address"=>"add", "clinic_zip_code"=>"34334", "clinic_city"=>"adsd", "clinic_municipality"=>"sadsa", "clinic_about"=>"dasds", "clinic_mail"=>"kvnana@yaoo.dk", "clinic_phone"=>"24210566", "clinic_website"=>""}, "commit"=>"Gem"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 96 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/clinics_controller.rb:25
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)



ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError):

app/controllers/clinics_controller.rb:25:in `create'
```

Comment: Look what params are being passed into action carefully. Plus you need to use [strong params](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html).

Comment: Why you use `<%= f.simple_fields_for(:clinics) do |p| %>` ?  Try to remove it

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for proper formatting, makes it easier to skim through the code.

Comment: Share the content of `clinics_fields` partial as well

Answer (score 0):

Change your **new.html.erb** to

```
<div id="ClinicGenerel" class="TabBlock">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content clinic">
      <h2 class="page-title">Generel information</h2>
      <%= simple_form_for [@clinic] do |f| %>
        <%= render 'clinics_fields', :f => f %>
        <div class="submit-container">
          <%= f.submit "Gem", :class => 'btn blue'  %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and try again. 
`<%= f.simple_fields_for(:clinics) do |p| %>` needs to be removed since `<%= f.simple_fields_for(:clinics) do |p| %>` will try to loop over `clinics` `association` of `clinic` which doesn't exist.

Comment: I've followed your suggestion, and updated the code, but now I'm getting this error - ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in ClinicsController#create

Answer (score 0):

From the codebase you shared, it seems you confused how to create nested relationship in a single request. i.e., Create user and clinic in single request per say in your case above.

There are couple of solution to just make it work.

1. Refer right parameters

`Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"1MpJgYCodgCLbJI2i5pZEjAV/a0qvJRHuLaSaim9Y3byHDAAqa4IbogbJNEzPTpyDNMRM3Wz5UFRU00CcBOYBQ==", "clinic"=>{"clinics"=>{"clinic_name"=>"My clinic", "clinic_address"=>"sdd", "clinic_zip_code"=>"343443", "clinic_city"=>"sadsasa", "clinic_municipality"=>"dsd", "clinic_about"=>"sasd", "clinic_mail"=>"kvnirva@yaho.dk", "clinic_phone"=>"24210866", "clinic_website"=>""}}, "commit"=>"Gem"}`

If you look at your log, you won't find any key `clinics_attributes` but you are trying to get via `params[:clinics_attributes]` in `create` action which will return `nil`

Quick Fix: Replace `params[:clinics_attributes]` with `params[:clinic][:clinics]` in you `create` action

2. Better version is what suggested by @sahil-grover in above answer.

But you still have to understand the structure of params and adjust how you access it.

With that change you will need to replace `params[:clinics_attributes]` with `params[:clinic]` in you `create` action

3. Little better version to solution 2 is to use strong params(`user_params` in your case)

Comment: I've followed the answer suggested by @sahil-grover. I've updated the code in my question. But now I'm getting this error - ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in ClinicsController#create

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it working by changing 
 `@clinic = current_user.clinics.new(params[:clinic])` to 
`@clinic = current_user.clinics.new(clinic_params)`
 
and instead of def user_params I've added this

```
def clinic_params
  params.require(:clinic).permit(:id, :clinic_name, :clinic_address, :clinic_zip_code, :clinic_municipality, :clinic_about, :clinic_mail, :clinic_phone, :clinic_website, :clinic_city)
end
```